# Can you puncture a tire with a Swiss Army knife?

Tags: road-vehicles, weapons

On films and TV you always see characters puncture a regular car tire with something like a folding knife or a swiss army knife. How hard would it be in real life to do this?

Comment: @woodchips or you can go to your local garage and ask to experiment on the old (bald) tires

Comment: Interesting question although the _how hard_ part is a bit unspecific.

Comment: Just a tip: If you're going to experiment, use a fixed blade knife with a hand guard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**

[This video advert](http://youtu.be/xccLyHSYRqA?t=1m17s) shows a man easily puncturing and cutting a tire with a pocket knife.

[This Mythbusters episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJBCpUDrqvA#t=231s) shows a snippet of Adam Savage puncturing a tire with a knife in the first 30 seconds. [Hat-tip: @ratchetfreak]

Comment: One day, the police are going to seize my computer records over some misunderstanding, and I am going to have some explaining to do about my search history. "So, tell me again why you were searching for 'tyre-slashing knifes'?"

Comment: I don't like this answer. The only proof given is an advertisement. We all know nobody ever lies or exaggerates in ads.

Comment: I'm skeptical.  The video shows a tire not under pressure.  I think a fully inflated tire would react differently.

Comment: -1, somewhat circular. Uses the same type of reference material (scripted video or film) that the OP expressed skepticism about.

Comment: I am the first to agree that if there was an answer from peer-reviewed journal article about a reproduced experiment, we should vote that up over this. However, I see this - a low budget advert presented as (non-fiction) demonstration and subject to Fair Trading laws - as far more convincing than a Hollywood movie - willing to use a special-effects department and deception to advance the fictional plot-line. It isn't extraordinary proof, but the claim is fairly prosaic, and I see enough to provisionally accept it until counter evidence is provided.

Comment: Chris: The tire is under some pressure. My intuition (*Danger: Argument from intuition!*) is that an inflated tire would be *easier* to puncture, like taut cloth is easier to cut.

Comment: ok I un-accepted this answer (sorry), does anyone have a video that looks more credible? Otherwise I'll just accept this one.

Comment: [mythbusters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OJBCpUDrqvA#t=231s) don't fake it

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Nice. Will edit that in.